# VS 2015 Cordova remote IOS build connection fail error on PUT

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I've been pulling my hair out on this one for days, and hope I get a lead here.

I've been developing an IOS and Android App with Cordova. Android is a breeze, and after MANY machinations I managed to get an IOS build to work on my iPhone 6s. However, when I did a rebuild on my VS project things stopped working. The remotebuild server is obviously running on the MAC (remotebuild --secure false) and the settings in VS are correct, secure=false, no pin, at local IP address 192.168.1.119. The build starts and the server shows:

```
...
Saving build request payload to : ...
POST /cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=6.0.0&cfg=debug&loglevel=warn - - ms - -
```

The VS log output is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Customer App, Configuration: Debug iOS ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 4.4.1 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.40
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 6.0.0 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Users\Owner\Perforce\GoShare\Blank\Ionic Blank\bld\iOS\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Users\Owner\Perforce\GoShare\Blank\Ionic Blank\bin\iOS\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: iOS
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: ios
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: Customer App
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Users\Owner\Perforce\GoShare\Blank\Ionic Blank
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\Owner\Perforce\GoShare\Blank\Blank
1>  ------    buildServerUrl: http://192.168.1.119:3000/cordova
1>  ------    buildTarget: iOSEmulatoriPhone5
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------ Platform ios already exists
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins: cordova-plugin-device@1.1.1,cordova-plugin-device-orientation@1.0.2,cordova-plugin-file@4.1.1,cordova-plugin-geolocation@2.1.0,cordova-plugin-splashscreen@3.1.0,cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.1.2,cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.2.1,ionic-plugin-keyboard@1.0.9
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins:
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins:
1>  ------ Incremental Build: false
1>  ------ Submitting new build request to: http://<ip address>:3000/cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=6.0.0&cfg=debug&loglevel=warn
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: Non-secure connection to http://192.168.1.119:3000/cordova could not be established. Verify that the build server is not running in secure mode.
1>  Error Non-secure connection to http://192.168.1.119:3000/cordova could not be established. Verify that the build server is not running in secure mode.

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've verified that http://:3000 returns:

Remote build Express server open for business on port 3000

I have no idea would be causing this failure at the PUT. I've tried everything I can think of.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Does the connection only fail after uploading for a little while, or does it fail immediately when it gets there? And do you have any proxies configured? It looks like the connection is being disconnected unexpectedly while uploading your project.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova team at Microsoft. Right now, we're investigating ways to make it easier for developers to recover from remote build errors in VS. It would be great to chat with you about this issue. Customer feedback is the number one way we make product design decisions, so I’d love it if you could make time for a 20min phone call this week or next to talk about how you understand and overcome build issues. jomatthi [at] Microsoft [dot] com